# Can't install CDH 5.0, Hangs at 40%

Tags: installation, cloudera-cdh, bigdata

I can't seem to install CDH 5.0, I'm running the binary installer.  When I run the binary installer for CDH 5.0, it gets 40% of the way through and just hangs, I have waited up to 45 minutes before and it makes no progress.  At 40% the installer screen says "cloudera-manager-installer".

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: what is your system details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works. The hang at 40% is normal. It passes after